# "Thank you for coming" or "thank you for coming in"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Let's say I have a problem with a computer, so I ask a friend to come to my place to help me fix it, which he does. Do I say ***thank you for coming*** or ***thank you for coming in***. Is there any difference between *come* and *come in* in the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference and *come in* is not natural in that context.

There are a number of adverbs and prepositions that can follow *come* and they alter its meaning; sometimes subtly, sometimes dramatically.

In this case, the difference between *thanks for coming* and *thanks for coming in* is subtle.

*Thanks for coming* works in this context. It is applicable to situations that involve traveling to someplace. There seems to be some kind of rule about the distance traveled, though, because I wouldn't thank my colleague for "coming" to my desk. Instead, I might say, "thanks for coming by" or "thanks for coming over here."

*Thanks for coming in* would work in similar situations, but not this exact one. *Come in* has a couple of uses. It can be used to describe entering a space. It can also be used to describe traveling to a place, but only specific kinds of places.

Probably the most common place to *come into* is *the office* or *work*.  If I'm sick, I might tell my manager, "I'm not coming in (to work/to the office) today."  If I was supposed to have the day off, but I agreed to trade shifts with someone, my boss might say, "Thanks for coming in on such short notice."

This also works when describing *coming* to see the doctor, or the dentist, or any place where you have an appointment.

On the other hand, if my wife *comes* to visit me at my office on her lunch break, she is not *coming in* (she is *coming over*, *coming by*, *coming to see me*).

It's not entirely clear to me when we can use *come in*.  It's something like when you're coming to the place where you work, or to a place where someone else works and you have an appointment with them.

Comment: One possibility, is when the police ask you to come to be interrogated about your wife's disappearance. Then, "Have a seat. Thank you for coming in."

Answer (score 0):

Well "come in" means to enter the room or building.  That is not what you are thanking the person for.

On the other hand "come" means "make the journey to here".

Certainly you want to thank the person for coming (and making a possibly long journey) and not for coming in.